# Creating transparent background in auto sized PNG's on ImageMagick and PHP

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick

How should I change this code so that it  gives me transparent backgrounded PNG?

```
<?php
    header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
    passthru("convert -fill red -pointsize 72 -font TR.Matisse.ITC.TTF -gravity Center label:'Font Test' PNG:-");
?>
```

PS: I dont want to give image size as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set  `-transparent color`, `-transparent-color color`, `-background color` or `-alpha type`

Have a look here: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
passthru("convert -background transparent -fill red -pointsize 72 -font TR.Matisse.ITC.TTF -gravity Center label:'Font Test' PNG:-");
?>
```

Comment: strange, i've tested the code on localhost it works perfect for me. I've got installed ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 on an OpenSuse desktop.

Comment: Hmm! Its so strange my convert -Version: ImageMagick 6.7.5-6 2012-02-22 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: OpenMP

Comment: Are you useing Q16 or Q8? By the way mine is CentOS

Comment: I'm Using Q16 (I need more chars)

Comment: convert --version prints:Version: ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2011-10-19 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP